# Servlet ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, twilio, classnotfoundexception

I am developing a web app in java using Servlets and jsp that contains the ability to send a SMS using the Twilio API. On their website (www.twilio.com) there is a sample main method that can be used to send an SMS. When I run that method I have no issues and the SMS sends. 
However when I try to send it from my Servlet I get a `ClassNotFoundException` (for either `TwilioRestClient` or `TwilioRestException`) even though the exact same code runs when it is contained in a main method. I think it is something to do with the jar files even though I have added them to my build path and imported them in all the classes.

I have tried everything and searched everywhere online for an answer. I'd be very grateful for any help.

JSP Code:

```jsp
<form action="SentTextServlet" method="get">
    <br>Send Text<br>
    <input type="text" name="textSent" style="height: 250px; width: 500px;" ><br>
    <button type="submit" name="btnPressed" value="<%= session.getAttribute("value")  %>">
        <p>Send Text Message</p>
    </button>
    <button type="submit" name="btnPressed" value="2"><p>Cancel</p></button>
</form>
```

ServletCode:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String text = request.getParameter("textSent");
    String selection = request.getParameter("btnPressed");
    String user = request.getParameter("user");
    TextProcedure texting = new TextProcedure(selection, text);             
}

public static void sendTextMessage(String student, String textMessage) throws TwilioRestException {
    TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN);
    // Build a filter for the MessageList
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Body", textMessage));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("To", phonenumber));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("From", phonenumber));
    MessageFactory messageFactory = client.getAccount().getMessageFactory();
    Message message = messageFactory.create(params);
    message.getSid();
}
```

Comment: Exception stack trace would be helpful. Can you update your question with it?

Comment: most likely you are missing jar files. You need to keep them in WEB-INF/lib folder and not in build path as we usually do.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add Twilio client library jar file to your `WEB-INF/lib` directory. By the looks of it, the war file being deployed is missing it.

Or if you are running your Web Application within an IDE like Eclipse, Make sure that the Deployment Assembly is configured to copy the dependency jars into `WEB-INF/lib`